# What are and how do I use OpenSSL BIO pairs?

Tags: openssl, key-pair

What exactly is a BIO pair in OpenSSL, and how is it intended to be used?  I've already checked the OpenSSL docs, but any details are few and far between.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A BIO in OpenSSL is similar to a File handle.  You use a pair of them to communicate with each other securely like you would with two sockets.  The best explanation I've found is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130327081616/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl/index.html).

I also got a lot of use out of [Herong Yang's site](http://www.herongyang.com/crypto/) a few months ago when I had to write an application using OpenSSL.  The sections on creating and signing certificates using OpenSSL and keytool were a big help when it came to testing my application.

Comment: Kudos for using the internet archive instead of a link to the raw page. It never would have occurred to me, but it solves the "broken link" problem beautifully.

Answer (score 7):

A BIO pair are two source/sink BIOs that are bound together.  Anything that is written to one can be read from the other.  If you have two BIOS already, you can join them together using BIO_make_bio_pair.  Or you can create a new BIO pair with BIO_new_bio_pair.

One use mentioned in the Network Security with OpenSSL book (see page 111) is that the pair can be bound to a SSL engine.  Anything written to the BIO pair will be read by the SSL engine.  Anything written to the BIO pair can be read from.  OpenSSL has a sample of this (see ssl/ssltest.c)

Answer (score 1):

I've written about OpenSSL BIO pairs as a part of [a general answer about OpenSSL BIOs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51672134/5447906):

> A "bio" BIO (`BIO_s_bio`). It is a pipe-like BIO. A pair of such BIOs can be created. Data written to one BIO in the pair will be placed for reading to the second BIO in the pair. And vice versa. It is similar to memory BIO, but memory BIO places data to itself and pipe BIO places data to the BIO which it is paired with.

And also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51632606/5447906):

> But in addition there is a BIO called `BIO_s_bio` which has a pipe-like functionality. A pair of such BIOs can be created. Any data written to the first BIO in the pair of `BIO_s_bio` objects will be read from the second BIO in the pair. And vice versa: writing data to the second BIO will result in reading this data from the first BIO. So `BIO_s_bio` can be used instead of `BIO_s_mem`. Passing a single instance of `BIO_s_bio` object to the `SSL_set_bio` function would be enough. Application receives data and writes it to its BIO in the `BIO_s_bio` pair. OpenSSL will then get this data from its BIO in the pair. OpenSSL writes data to its BIO in the pair, and the application gets this data from its BIO in turn.