OpenSSL BIO_Read Returns negative value
continue my journey from here: Cannot add TLS to my HTTP Server, clients cannot connect to it
where I am trying to implement HTTPS server
HTTPServer
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using OpenSsl;

namespace RawHttpListener
{
    #region HTTPParser
    public interface IHTTPClientHandler
    {
        Task HTTPClientConnected(HttpContext ctx);
    }

    public class HttpContext
    {
        public HttpRequest Request { get; set; }
        public HttpResponse Response { get; set; }

        public HttpContext(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
        {
            Request = request;
            Response = response;
        }
    }

    public class HttpRequest
    {
        public string HttpMethod { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string UserHostName { get; set; }
        public string UserAgent { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }

        public HttpRequest(string httpMethod, string url, string userHostName, string userAgent)
        {
            HttpMethod = httpMethod;
            Url = url;
            UserHostName = userHostName;
            UserAgent = userAgent;
        }
    }

    public class HttpResponse
    {
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public Encoding ContentEncoding { get; set; }
        public long ContentLength64 { get; set; }
        public Stream OutputStream { get; set; }

        public HttpResponse(Stream outputStream)
        {
            OutputStream = outputStream;
        }
    }

    public class HTTPParser : Stream
    {
        private readonly IHTTPClientHandler _clientHandler;
        private readonly Stream _baseStream;
        private readonly MemoryStream _memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        private const int BufferSize = 4096;
        private readonly byte[] _buffer = new byte[BufferSize];

        public HTTPParser(Stream baseStream, IHTTPClientHandler clientHandler)
        {
            _baseStream = baseStream;
            _clientHandler = clientHandler;
        }

        public async Task HandleClientConnected()
        {
            int bytesRead;
            // Read the incoming data until the connection is closed
            while ((bytesRead = await _baseStream.ReadAsync(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                await _memoryStream.WriteAsync(_buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                // Check for the end of the request (empty line means headers end)
                if (bytesRead < BufferSize) break;
            }

            // Convert the raw request to a string
            string rawRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_memoryStream.ToArray());
            //Console.WriteLine("Raw HTTP Request:");
            //Console.WriteLine(rawRequest);

            // Handle the HTTP request
            await HandleHttpRequest(rawRequest);
        }

        private async Task HandleHttpRequest(string rawRequest)
        {
            // Fill the MyOwnHttpListenerContext object and call the HTTPClientConnected method
            var lines = rawRequest.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (lines.Length == 0) return;

            // Parse the request line (first line)
            var requestLine = lines[0].Split(' ');
            if (requestLine.Length < 3) return;

            string method = requestLine[0]; 
            string url = requestLine[1];     
            string httpVersion = requestLine[2]; 

            // Extract headers
            string userHostName = string.Empty;
            string userAgent = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++) // Skip the request line
            {
                if (lines[i].StartsWith("Host:"))
                {
                    userHostName = lines[i].Substring(6).Trim(); // Skip "Host: "
                }
                else if (lines[i].StartsWith("User-Agent:"))
                {
                    userAgent = lines[i].Substring(12).Trim(); // Skip "User-Agent: "
                }
            }

            // Create the request and response objects
            var request = new HttpRequest(method, url, userHostName, userAgent);
            var response = new HttpResponse(_baseStream);

            var ctx = new HttpContext(request, response);
            await _clientHandler.HTTPClientConnected(ctx);
        }

        // Implementing abstract members of Stream class
        public override bool CanRead => _baseStream.CanRead;
        public override bool CanSeek => _baseStream.CanSeek;
        public override bool CanWrite => _baseStream.CanWrite;
        public override long Length => _baseStream.Length;
        public override long Position { get => _baseStream.Position; set => _baseStream.Position = value; }

        public override void Flush() => _baseStream.Flush();

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => _baseStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);

        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => _baseStream.Seek(offset, origin);

        public override void SetLength(long value) => _baseStream.SetLength(value);

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => _baseStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    #endregion
    #region RawHttpServer
    public class RawHttpServer : IHTTPClientHandler
    {
        public string ipAddress = string.Empty; // Change to your desired IP address
        public int port; // Use a non-privileged port for testing
        bool isHTTPS;

        public RawHttpServer()
        {
            this.ipAddress = "172.0.0.1";
            this.port = 80;
            this.isHTTPS = false;
        }
        public RawHttpServer(IPAddress ip, int port, bool isHTTPS)
        {
            this.ipAddress = ip.ToString();
            this.port = port;
            this.isHTTPS = isHTTPS;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), port);
            tcpListener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine($"Listening for connections on {ipAddress}:{port}");

            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine($"Accepted connection from {tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint}");

                Task.Run(() => HandleClient(tcpClient));
            }
        }
        
        private async Task HandleClient(TcpClient tcpClient)
        {
            using (NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream())
            {
                HTTPParser httpParser;
                if (!this.isHTTPS)
                {
                    // For HTTP connections
                    httpParser = new HTTPParser(stream, this);
                    await httpParser.HandleClientConnected(); // Handle the client connection
                }
                else
                {
                    // For HTTPS connections
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Starting TLS Handshake...");

                        //using (var tlsStream = new TlsStream(tcpClient, "cert.pem", "key.pem", new[] { "h2", "http/1.1" })) //If using BIO //If I use socket handle, I have to provide TCPClient object
                        using (var tlsStream = new TlsStream(stream, "cert.pem", "key.pem", new[] { "h2", "http/1.1" })) //If using BIO
                        {
                            // Perform the TLS handshake
                            await tlsStream.DoHandshakeAsync();
                            Console.WriteLine("TLS Handshake completed.");
                        
                            string applicationProtocol = tlsStream.GetNegotiatedApplicationProtocol();
                            Console.WriteLine($"Negotiated Application Protocol: {applicationProtocol}");
                        
                            // Create a new HTTP parser using the TlsStream for the connection
                            httpParser = new HTTPParser(tlsStream, this);
                            await httpParser.HandleClientConnected(); // Handle the client connection
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error during TLS handshake: {ex.Message}");
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                    }
                }
            }
            tcpClient.Close();
        }

        public async Task HTTPClientConnected(HttpContext ctx)
        {
            // Print out some info about the request
            Console.WriteLine($"Received request: {ctx.Request.HttpMethod} {ctx.Request.Url}");
            Console.WriteLine($"User Host Name: {ctx.Request.UserHostName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"User Agent: {ctx.Request.UserAgent}");

            if (ctx.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("POST BODY: ");
                Console.WriteLine(ctx.Request.Body);
            }

            // Write the response info
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>");
            ctx.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            ctx.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = data.Length;

            // Write out to the response stream (asynchronously), then close it
            await ctx.Response.OutputStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close(); // Close the output stream
            Console.WriteLine("Response sent to the client.");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    //Our main class here
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool isHTTPS = true;
            RawHttpServer server = new RawHttpServer(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.88.12"), 443, isHTTPS);
            server.Start();

            //Usefull: https://github.com/FoxCouncil/LibFoxyProxy/tree/72a32174a7adc71885c8b0a2758eab173f5a0d4a
        }
    }
}

in both working and non working cases I use the same OpenSSL wrappings, which I had to put here: https://hastebin.com/share/pirutogogu.csharp
I was able to make it work using sockets, working TLSStream using sockets looks like this
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OpenSsl
{
    public class TlsStream : Stream
    {
        private readonly TcpClient _tcpClient;
        private readonly Stream _innerStream;
        private IntPtr _ctx;
        private IntPtr _ssl;

        static TlsStream()
        {
            OpenSsl.SSL_library_init();
            OpenSsl.SSL_load_error_strings();
            OpenSsl.ERR_load_BIO_strings();
            OpenSsl.OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
        }

        public TlsStream(TcpClient tcpClient, Stream innerStream, string certificatePath, string privateKeyPath, IEnumerable<string> protocols)
        {
            _tcpClient = tcpClient;

            _ctx = OpenSsl.SSL_CTX_new(OpenSsl.TLSv1_2_method());
            if (_ctx == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to create SSL context.");
            }

            OpenSsl.SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(_ctx, 1);

            if (OpenSsl.SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(_ctx, certificatePath, 1) != 1)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to load certificate file.");
            }

            if (OpenSsl.SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(_ctx, privateKeyPath, 1) != 1)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to load private key file.");
            }

            _ssl = OpenSsl.SSL_new(_ctx);

            // Set the file descriptor (socket FD) directly on the SSL object
            //var socket = tcpClient.Client;  // Get the underlying socket
            //OpenSsl.SSL_set_fd(_ssl, socket.Handle.ToInt32());

            Console.WriteLine("[TLS Stream] Setting file descriptor for SSL...");
            OpenSsl.SSL_set_fd(_ssl, (int)_tcpClient.Client.Handle); // Set the file descriptor for SSL
        }

        public override bool CanRead => true;
        public override bool CanWrite => true;
        public override bool CanSeek => false;
        public override long Length => throw new NotSupportedException();
        public override long Position
        {
            get => throw new NotSupportedException();
            set => throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => throw new NotSupportedException();
        public override void SetLength(long value) => throw new NotSupportedException();

        public override void Flush() => FlushAsync(default(CancellationToken)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            return ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            WriteAsync(buffer, offset, count).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        public override async Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Call SSL_read directly
            var ret = OpenSsl.SSL_read(_ssl, buffer, offset, count);
            if (ret <= 0)
            {
                throw new IOException("Error reading from SSL stream.");
            }
            return ret;
        }

        public override Task WriteAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Call SSL_write directly
            var ret = OpenSsl.SSL_write(_ssl, buffer, offset, count);
            if (ret <= 0)
            {
                throw new IOException("Error writing to SSL stream.");
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public async Task DoHandshakeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            // Set the SSL object to expect the client handshake
            OpenSsl.SSL_set_accept_state(_ssl);

            // Set a timeout for the handshake process to avoid indefinite blocking
            var handshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            var handshakeTask = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                int ret = -1;

                try
                {
                    // Start handshake loop
                    while (true)
                    {
                        ret = OpenSsl.SSL_do_handshake(_ssl);
                        if (ret == 1)
                        {
                            // Handshake succeeded
                            return;
                        }

                        int error = OpenSsl.SSL_get_error(_ssl, ret);

                        if (error == OpenSsl.SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ || error == OpenSsl.SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE)
                        {
                            // Keep waiting for the handshake to complete
                            await Task.Delay(100); // Wait briefly before retrying
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // An actual error occurred
                            throw new IOException($"TLS handshake failed with error {error}");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    throw new IOException($"Handshake failed: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }, cancellationToken);

            // Ensure that the handshake doesn't run indefinitely
            if (await Task.WhenAny(handshakeTask, Task.Delay(handshakeTimeout, cancellationToken)) == handshakeTask)
            {
                await handshakeTask; // Propagate exception if any
            }
            else
            {
                throw new TimeoutException("TLS handshake timed out.");
            }
        }

        public string GetNegotiatedApplicationProtocol()
        {
            OpenSsl.SSL_get0_alpn_selected(_ssl, out var protocol);
            return protocol;
        }

        // Ensure resources are freed
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);

            if (_ssl != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                OpenSsl.SSL_free(_ssl);
                _ssl = IntPtr.Zero;
            }

            if (_ctx != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                OpenSsl.SSL_CTX_free(_ctx);
                _ctx = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }
    }
}

If I use BIO instead of sockets
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OpenSsl
{
    public class TlsStream : Stream
    {
        private static unsafe OpenSsl.alpn_select_cb_t _alpnSelectCallback = AlpnSelectCallback;

        private readonly Stream _innerStream;
        private readonly byte[] _protocols;
        private readonly GCHandle _protocolsHandle;

        private IntPtr _ctx;
        private IntPtr _ssl;
        private IntPtr _inputBio;
        private IntPtr _outputBio;

        private readonly byte[] _inputBuffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        private readonly byte[] _outputBuffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];

        static TlsStream()
        {
            OpenSsl.SSL_library_init();
            OpenSsl.SSL_load_error_strings();
            OpenSsl.ERR_load_BIO_strings();
            OpenSsl.OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
        }

        public TlsStream(Stream innerStream, string certificatePath, string privateKeyPath, IEnumerable<string> protocols)
        {
            _innerStream = innerStream;
            _protocols = ToWireFormat(protocols);
            _protocolsHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(_protocols);

            _ctx = OpenSsl.SSL_CTX_new(OpenSsl.TLSv1_2_method());

            if (_ctx == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to create SSL context.");
            }

            OpenSsl.SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(_ctx, 1);

            if (OpenSsl.SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(_ctx, certificatePath, 1) != 1)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to load certificate file.");
            }

            if (OpenSsl.SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(_ctx, privateKeyPath, 1) != 1)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to load private key file.");
            }

            OpenSsl.SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb(_ctx, _alpnSelectCallback, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(_protocolsHandle));

            _ssl = OpenSsl.SSL_new(_ctx);

            _inputBio = OpenSsl.BIO_new(OpenSsl.BIO_s_mem());
            OpenSsl.BIO_set_mem_eof_return(_inputBio, -1);

            _outputBio = OpenSsl.BIO_new(OpenSsl.BIO_s_mem());
            OpenSsl.BIO_set_mem_eof_return(_outputBio, -1);

            OpenSsl.SSL_set_bio(_ssl, _inputBio, _outputBio);
        }

        ~TlsStream()
        {
            if (_ssl != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                OpenSsl.SSL_free(_ssl);
            }

            if (_ctx != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                // This frees the BIOs.
                OpenSsl.SSL_CTX_free(_ctx);
            }

            if (_protocolsHandle.IsAllocated)
            {
                _protocolsHandle.Free();
            }
        }

        public override bool CanRead => true;
        public override bool CanWrite => true;

        public override bool CanSeek => false;
        public override long Length => throw new NotSupportedException();
        public override long Position
        {
            get => throw new NotSupportedException();
            set => throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => throw new NotSupportedException();
        public override void SetLength(long value) => throw new NotSupportedException();

        public override void Flush()
        {
            FlushAsync(default(CancellationToken)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            return ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            WriteAsync(buffer, offset, count).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        // Method to retrieve the OpenSSL error queue message
        private string GetOpenSslErrorMessage()
        {
            var errCode = OpenSsl.ERR_get_error();
            if (errCode == 0)
                return "No OpenSSL errors in the queue.";

            var errMsg = OpenSsl.ERR_reason_error_string(errCode);
            return $"OpenSSL error code {errCode}: {errMsg}";
        }

        public override async Task FlushAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var pending = OpenSsl.BIO_ctrl_pending(_outputBio);

            while (pending > 0)
            {
                var count = OpenSsl.BIO_read(_outputBio, _outputBuffer, 0, _outputBuffer.Length);

                //Console.WriteLine($"BIO_read returned: {count}");
                //Console.WriteLine($"Buffer Length: {_outputBuffer.Length}");

                // Handle BIO_read errors
                if (count < 0)
                {
                    string errorMessage = GetOpenSslErrorMessage();
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"BIO_read returned a negative value, indicating an error: {errorMessage}");
                }

                if (count > _outputBuffer.Length)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count), "BIO_read returned a value larger than the buffer size.");
                }
                
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    await _innerStream.WriteAsync(_outputBuffer, 0, count, cancellationToken);
                }

                pending = OpenSsl.BIO_ctrl_pending(_outputBio);
            }
        }

        public override async Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (OpenSsl.BIO_ctrl_pending(_inputBio) == 0)
            {
                var bytesRead = await _innerStream.ReadAsync(_inputBuffer, 0, _inputBuffer.Length, cancellationToken);

                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                OpenSsl.BIO_write(_inputBio, _inputBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            return OpenSsl.SSL_read(_ssl, buffer, offset, count);
        }

        public override Task WriteAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            OpenSsl.SSL_write(_ssl, buffer, offset, count);

            return FlushAsync(cancellationToken);
        }


        public async Task DoHandshakeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            OpenSsl.SSL_set_accept_state(_ssl);

            var count = 0;

            try
            {
                while ((count = await _innerStream.ReadAsync(_inputBuffer, 0, _inputBuffer.Length, cancellationToken)) > 0)
                {
                    if (count == 0)
                    {
                        throw new IOException("TLS handshake failed: the inner stream was closed.");
                    }

                    OpenSsl.BIO_write(_inputBio, _inputBuffer, 0, count);

                    var ret = OpenSsl.SSL_do_handshake(_ssl);

                    if (ret != 1)
                    {
                        var error = OpenSsl.SSL_get_error(_ssl, ret);

                        if (error != 2)
                        {
                            throw new IOException($"TLS handshake failed: {nameof(OpenSsl.SSL_do_handshake)} error {error}.");
                        }
                    }

                    await FlushAsync(cancellationToken);

                    if (ret == 1)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _protocolsHandle.Free();
            }
        }

        public string GetNegotiatedApplicationProtocol()
        {
            OpenSsl.SSL_get0_alpn_selected(_ssl, out var protocol);
            return protocol;
        }

        private static unsafe int AlpnSelectCallback(IntPtr ssl, out byte* @out, out byte outlen, byte* @in, uint inlen, IntPtr arg)
        {
            var protocols = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(arg);
            var server = (byte[])protocols.Target;

            fixed (byte* serverPtr = server)
            {
                return OpenSsl.SSL_select_next_proto(out @out, out outlen, serverPtr, (uint)server.Length, @in, (uint)inlen) == OpenSsl.OPENSSL_NPN_NEGOTIATED
                    ? OpenSsl.SSL_TLSEXT_ERR_OK
                    : OpenSsl.SSL_TLSEXT_ERR_NOACK;
            }
        }

        private static byte[] ToWireFormat(IEnumerable<string> protocols)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[protocols.Count() + protocols.Sum(protocol => protocol.Length)];

            var offset = 0;
            foreach (var protocol in protocols)
            {
                buffer[offset++] = (byte)protocol.Length;
                offset += Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(protocol, 0, protocol.Length, buffer, offset);
            }

            return buffer;
        }
    }
}

I always get this error, and server closes connection imidiatly, after the handshake is over, same thing if using firefox or openSSL like this: openssl s_client -connect domain.local:443 -CAfile XWDS.crt
Listening for connections on 192.168.88.12:443
Accepted connection from 192.168.88.12:62764
Starting TLS Handshake...
Error during TLS handshake: BIO_read returned a negative value, indicating an error: No OpenSSL errors in the queue.
   at OpenSsl.TlsStream.<FlushAsync>d__30.MoveNext() in C:\Users\cliente\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Network\OpenSSLWrapperTest\OpenSSLWrapper\TlsStream.cs:line 147
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at OpenSsl.TlsStream.<DoHandshakeAsync>d__33.MoveNext() in C:\Users\cliente\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Network\OpenSSLWrapperTest\OpenSSLKestrelWrapper\TlsStream.cs:line 218
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at RawHttpListener.RawHttpServer.<InnerOnConnectionAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C
:\Users\cliente\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Network\OpenSSLWrapperTest\OpenSSLWrapper\Program.cs:line 195
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at RawHttpListener.RawHttpServer.<HandleClient>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Users\cliente\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Network\OpenSSLWrapperTest\OpenSSLWrapper\Program.cs:line 245

for some reason I cannot get any error out of this, so I would know whats happening
You can see OpenSSL Output here: https://hastebin.com/share/lumeyihexa.yaml
I am not sure why I cannot make this work with BIO, would realy like to use BIO

I strongly suspect memory BIOs from BIO_s_mem() do not support blocking reads so your reads simply return EOF when there's no data. See https://docs.openssl.org/master/man3/SSL_set_blocking_mode/#synopsis  See this for another alternative:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439407/what-are-and-how-do-i-use-openssl-bio-pairs

thnx, is there any way to verify that, also where do I do blocking reads, I do use await everywhere I can, so realy not sure now. Also how do I fix this then?
